# How to make an image the background of Grid View in Android?

Tags: android, gridview, android-image

I am making an app for my class final that uses a GridView in android.
I know how to make the background a certain color using Hex, but I wanted to know if it is possible to use an image like a .png as the background instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just like any other `View` inheritor you can set the background in XML to be a drawable resource:

```
<GridView ...
    android:background="@drawable/my_image"
    ...
/>
```

or in code you can set the background resource:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `gridView.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.<pictureid>);`.